# Exit a shell script properly in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell

I have a shell script that create for me a project with the full structure, git repository etc...
The problem is that I can't use the terminal after the execution of the test. Here is a sample of my script :

```
read -p "Have you created the remote repository : $repo.git ? [y/n] " ok
if [ $ok != "y" ]; then
    echo "You must create the remote repository before."
    exit 0;
fi

git init
# Rest of the script...
```

When I type "n" as an answer, the terminal displays this (for non-french people, "Opération terminée" means "End of the operation") :

```
You must create the remote repository before.
logout

[Opération terminée]
```

And I can't use it anymore. The only way to use it again is to close the tab and open another one. Maybe the problem is in the `exit 0` ? How to exit the script properly ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you invoking the script?  Is it in a file called `script.sh` with `0755` perms and `#!/bin/sh` at the top and you are calling it with `./script.sh` or `/path/to/script.sh`?

Comment: No, I have a function `init-project` in my `.bash_profile` and I call this function

Comment: It needs to be in a shell script which accepts arguments, not interrogates the user.  This will then run in a *sub-shell* and all will be well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this runs from the bash_profile, `exit 0` actually closes the shell based on its context. Normally, a script is what's calling the function so it exits not the shell. For example, if you run `echo "hello world"; exit 0;` directly in the shell then it closes the shell because that's the context where exit occurs.

As suggested by @mklement0, replace `exit 0` with `return`.

Comment: Perfect, replacing exit by return fixed it ! Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you backgrounding the function with `&` at the end of line somewhere? That would work like `sleep 1 &` and only print that it's done once you press Enter. The output when the process ends depends on the shell, but in Bash 4.2 it looks like this:

```
$ sleep 1 &
[1] 11166
$ # Just press Enter after more than a second
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
```